# What is the correct way to convert string into UTF-8 encoded URL

Tags: python-3.x

```
Recieverphno = input("Please enter the phone number of the person you want to send the 
whatsapp message to: ")
Text = input('Please enter the text you want this person to recieve: ')
n = input('Please enter the number of times you want to send the person: ')
Text.replace(" ", "%20")
Text.replace("?", "%3F")
Text.replace("!", "%21")
Text.replace(",", "%2C")
WhatsappAPIURL = str('https://wa.me/'+Recieverphno+'?text='+Text)
print(WhatsappAPIURL)
```

I want to replace the string and encode it in UTF-8 format

Answer (score 0):

For this you'd need urlencoder

In python 3 it could be achieved using [urllib.parse.quote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote)...

```
import urllib.parse
WhatsappAPIURL = urllib.parse.quote(str('https://wa.me/'+Recieverphno+'?text='+Text))
```

Optionally, if you are already using requests in your project,

```
from requests.utils import requote_uri
requote_uri(str('https://wa.me/'+Recieverphno+'?text='+Text))
```